# A content creation tool using Image processing in Android Studio

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, image-processing, video-processing

I recently came across an app with fascinating features that I would like to incorporate into my project in Android Studio.

The app I found allows users to create short videos by inputting images with music, which can then be used as WhatsApp status updates or as short videos like Instagram reels, YouTube shorts and TikTok.

The app has a list of videos on the home screen, and I believe it's an API-based list of short videos with numerous categories. When the user opens a video, theres a button on it (in the UI) which accesses the user's device's gallery, and after selecting couple of images, Those Images from the gallery are mixed with existing short videos which are in the list on home screen from the backend API and in the end it produces a short video with good effects with animations and video mixing as an output.

```
Below are the links to the video content creation tool, to understand more.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mast.status.video.edit
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/HbgVvi8Fb4Q?feature=share
https://mastinapp.com/
```

I am really looking forward for help and guidance on Image Processing in Android, And curious to know necessary steps to start with my project.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have edited, Thankyou